# Dynamically add li to ul javascript

Tags: javascript, html-lists

I have an array of names and I want to show them on my page.
I created an empty ul in my html

```
<ul id="friendsList">
</ul>
```

And now I want to add the names to this ol but I doesn't work

```
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    var name = names[i];
    var li = document.createElement('li', name);
    li.parentElement('friendsList');
}
```

Error:
Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: li.parentElement is not a function

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to append your `li` to `ul`. This `document.createElement('li', name);` won't work.

**Syntax**

```
document.createElement(tagName[, options]);
```

> **tagName**:
>   A string that specifies the type of element to be created.
>
> **options** (Optional): 
>   An optional ElementCreationOptions object containing a single property named is, whose value is the tag name for a custom element previously defined using `customElements.define()`.

[document.createElement() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

```js
var names = ['John', 'Jane'];
var ul = document.getElementById("friendsList");

for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    var name = names[i];
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
    ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<ul id="friendsList">
</ul>
```

Comment: This works, now I will try to figure it out with my code. Thx!

Answer (score 4):

Try below example - use `appendChild` on your UL, which you will get using `getElementById()`:

```js
var names = ["John","Mike","George"]
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    var name = names[i];
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = name;  
    document.getElementById('friendsList').appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<ul id="friendsList"></ul>
```

Comment: This works, now I will try to figure it out with my code. Thx!

Answer (score 4):

[Node.parentElement](http://devdocs.io/dom/node/parentelement) is a read only property (ie if you want to inspect  the parent node of a given node)

If you want to insert nodes there are different ways:

one of the solution is to use the method [appendChild](http://devdocs.io/dom/node/appendchild) on the parent node.

If you want to avoid a reflow (the browser redraws the frame) one every insertion you can first [insert your elements in a document fragment](http://devdocs.io/dom/document/createdocumentfragment)

```
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
for(let name of names){
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = name;
  fragment.appendChild(li);
}
//now you add all the nodes in once
const container = document.getElementById('friendsList');
container.appendChild(fragment);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
// using Es6
let names = ['john','jane','smith'];
names.forEach((name)=>{
let li = document.createElement('li');
li.innerText = name;
document.getElementById('friendsList').appendChild(li);
})
```

```html
<ul id="friendsList"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `textContent` of the `<li>` and then append it to the `<ul>`.

```js
const list = document.getElementById('friendsList');
list.append(Object.assign(document.createElement('li'), {textContent: 'item text'}));
```

See:

- [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
- [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)
- [`Element#append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var friendsList = document.getElementById('friendsList');
var names = ["John","Mike","George"];
names.forEach(function (name) {
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = name;  
  friendsList.appendChild(li);
});
```

Comment: This works, now I will try to figure it out with my code. Thx!