# Fetching multiple data from JSON in lists

Tags: javascript, json

at the beginning I want to say that I checked a lot of solutions but none of it was straight accurate to my problem. I wonder if it's possible to fetch data from JSON (name, surname and id). In every of each list will be other data. The issue is length of lists will be as much as JSON's length so it has to be automatically generated, but unfortunately in promises, you are not allowed to make functions so what is the solution for that problem?

```js
const nameList = document.querySelector('.name-list')
const surnameList = document.querySelector('.surname-list')
const idList = document.querySelector('.id-list')


fetch('http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cuSKqtKmgi?indent=2')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

```css
body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <ul class="name-list">
    </ul>
    <ul class="surname-list">
    </ul>
    <ul class="id-list">
    </ul>
    <ul class="example">
        <li>Example1</li>
        <li>Example2</li>
        <li>Example3</li>
        <li>Example4</li>
        <li>Example5</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

That is only an exercise but will help me understand fetch more. If something is unclear feel free to ask :)

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "**but unfortunately in promises, you are not allowed to make functions**". Besides that, you can iterate over the `data` (*right where you `console.log`*) and insert items in the 3 lists.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I had `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: can't access property "forEach", data.person.name is undefined` error that's why I thought you're not allowed to do that, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.forEach` as follows:

```js
const nameList = document.querySelector('.name-list')
const surnameList = document.querySelector('.surname-list')
const idList = document.querySelector('.id-list')

fetch('http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cuSKqtKmgi?indent=2')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    const { person = [] } = data;
    person.forEach(({ name, surrname, id }) => {
      nameList.innerHTML += `<li>${name}</li>`;
      surnameList.innerHTML += `<li>${surrname}</li>`;
      idList.innerHTML += `<li>${id}</li>`;
    });
  });
```

```css
body{ display: flex; justify-content: space-around; }
```

```html
<ul class="name-list"></ul>
<ul class="surname-list"></ul>
<ul class="id-list"></ul>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted but can it be done in a different way instead of using innerHTML?

Comment: @Stairss check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47951287/dynamically-add-li-to-ul-javascript/47951374

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is simple like:

```
let names = []
let surnames = []
let ids = []

fetch('http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cuSKqtKmgi?indent=2')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {        
    data.person.forEach(item => {
      names.push(item.name)
      surnames.push(item.surname)
      ids.push(item.id)
    })
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it really helps :)